# Create an array from fields that are not null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to optimize a query of form `A.X = value OR B.Y.Z = value OR C.H = value` in Mongodb. DB engine uses 3 different indices to perform a query like this and then join results. It's somewhat slow so I decided to put everything in one array and create a multikey index on it. So I created an index and this query to update entries and populate it:

```
{
  '$addFields': { 
    'AllowedEntries': [ '$A.X', '$B.Y.Z', '$C.H' ]
  } 
}
```

It worked like a charm but then I realized that some of values are nulls and I want nulls out of array. So I went to this query:

```
{
  '$addFields': { 
    'AllowedEntries': { 
      '$map': { 
        'input': [ '$A.X', '$B.Y.Z', '$C.H' ], 
        'as': 'item', 
        'in': { 
          'columns': { 
            '$filter': { 
              'input': '$$item', 
              'as': 'elt', 
              'cond': { '$ne': [ '$$elt', null ] } 
            } 
          }
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Which doesn't work because of `input to $filter must be an array not binData` error. How can I do it atomically? In theory I could execute this query and then pull nulls out but I'd really like to do it in one update.

Comment: The $map shouldn't be required, $filter should be able to do that.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm not sure I'm getting your idea

Comment: The $filter operator is for picking elements from an array based on a boolean conditional, which is exactly what you are trying to do.  Check out the example at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html

Comment: Cool. Worked like a charm. Is it possible not to get only unique values? I tried `$addToSet` but failed. Also don't you want to post an answer? I'l mark it since it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with following solution, to put unique not-null items in a new field. Many thanks to @Joe for help

```
{
  '$addFields': { 
    'AllowedEntries': { 
      '$setUnion': [[], { 
        '$filter': { 
          'input': [  '$A.X', '$B.Y.Z', '$C.H' ], 
          'as': 'elt', 
          'cond': '$$elt' 
        } 
      }] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

note that `$setUnion` with empty array is used instead of `$addToSet` because the latter works with column names while the former works with any expression which is filter in our case.